# Implement Sliding Window Algorithm to Detect Spikes

Tags: python, outlier, dataframe

How do I implement sliding window algorithm with a window size of 10 and visualize the data iteratively to see spikes/possible outliers in the dataframe, using python? Please help a beginner.

Comment: Are you actually looking for an algorithm that detects spikes (anomaly detection), or simply a way to visualize data 10 observations at a time to manually look for spikes in the data?

Comment: $There are gems$ -: “Open Machine Learning Course. Topic 9. Part 1. Time series analysis in Python” https://medium.com/open-machine-learning-course/open-machine-learning-course-topic-9-time-series-analysis-in-python-a270cb05e0b3,“Open Machine Learning Course. Topic 9. Part 2. Predicting the future with Facebook Prophet” https://medium.com/open-machine-learning-course/open-machine-learning-course-topic-9-part-3-predicting-the-future-with-facebook-prophet-3f3af145cdc

Comment: Thanks @Aditya the resource you provided was extremely helpful! Ryan, I am looking to detect random spikes on data and smoothen them out, as well as to visualize them in smaller windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to DS-SE and to Data Science in general! :)

Your problem can be solved really easily in Python. Please, take a look at Pandas [DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) class to represent your data, it makes it really convenient because of all the pre-built methods that includes.

One of its methods is `pandas.DataFrame.rolling()` (see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html)) that does exactly what you asked for: rolling (sliding) window calculations, please take a look!

Hope it helps!

Comment: @pdko1 this is exactly what I was looking to do! Thanks so much!